# How can I find the neutral element of this algebraic structure

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, binary-operations

Given the algebraic structure $(Z×Z,⊥)$, with

$(a,b)⊥(c,d)=(a+c,bd)$

for each $a,b,c,d∈Z$.

How can I find the neutral element of $(Z×Z,⊥)$? Please help me.

Comment: You have to find an element $(x,y)$ such that $(a,b)⊥(x,y)=(a,b)$. Compute the LHS and the result will gives you the answer. Same approach of your previous (now deleted) post.

Comment: This isn't a "do my homework, *now*" site, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $e=(c,d).$

Thus, $a+c=a$ and $bd=b$ for all $b\in\mathbb Z$, which gives $c=0$ and $d=1$.

Easy to see that for all $x$ from our structure $$x\perp e=e\perp x=x.$$

Comment: So what's the neutral element?

Comment: $(0,1)$ of course.